# HTML/CSS The background-color is set to red in the code but once i open it in the browser it does not appear in red

Tags: html, css, web

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Navigation bar in html and css</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/style.css">
<style>
 * {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
font-family : verdana;
}
    
nav{
width : 100%;
height : 70px;
background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
<a href = "#">Home</a>
<a href = "#">Services</a>
<a href = "#">Portfolio</a>
<a href = "#">About</a>
<a href = "#">Contact</a>   
</nav>
</body>     
</html>
```

The background-color is set to red but when viewed in browser the background-color does not appear red would like to know where i've gone wrong.

Comment: what's inside style.css ?

Answer (score 0):

you should try this code :

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/style.css" />
```

hope you can solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a " when linking your css.

Should be:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/style.css">
```

Tested and works

Answer (score 0):

you might have another style for nav element in style.css

so if you want to override that style
use:

```
nav{
width : 100%;
height : 70px;
background-color: red !important; // for overriding already applied style if any.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
* {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
font-family : verdana;
}
    
nav{
width : 100%;
height : 70px;
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Navigation bar in html and css</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<nav>
<a href = "#" id="a">Home</a>
<a href = "#" id="a">Services</a>
<a href = "#" id="a">Portfolio</a>
<a href = "#" id="a">About</a>
<a href = "#" id="a">Contact</a>   
</nav>
</body>     
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Instead of providing code after HTML try to give color inside with color code in the `<nav>` tag

eg : `<nav style="background-color:#FF0000">`

Solution 2: If you using chrome press `ctrl + h` then on left side press clear history and pop up will come in that select/tick only **cached images and files** and than clear it.

hope you can solve this problem